# debootstrap does not extract libc6, does not create /sbin/ldconfig

Tags: 14.04, chroot, debootstrap

I am using dbootstrap to create a chroot root file system (Ubuntu 14.04), so that I can use it later to image another machine.  I specify all the necessary packages, and debootstrap seems to retrieve, validate, and begin extracting them all (including lib6c, which should include /sbin/ldcofig), but I get the following error:

```
user@computer:~$ debootstrap --arch=amd64 --include=....,libc6,.... /rootfs
...
...
I: Extracting libc6...
....
I: Extracting util-linux...
I: Extracting xz-utils...
I: Extracting zlib1g...
W: Failure trying to run: chroot /home/../rootfs /sbin/ldconfig
```

I believe that /sbin/ldconfig should have been created when libc6 was extracted (into the "rootfs"), but it is not create the file. This means that debootstrap cannot chroot that file, causing the error message above.

Why doesn't extracting libc6 result in /sbin/ldconfig being created? What else does debootstrap need here?

**Edit:** I have noticed that /bin/sh (also required to run the command that fails above)  is also missing, and therefore not extracted. Any idea why it is missing?

Comment: `/sbin/ldconfig` is in libc-bin not libc6. `/bin/sh` should be in dash. It might help to put the actual debootstrap line you are using so others can try to replicate the error.

Comment: Are you sure that `/sbin/ldconfig` is missing? From what you've pasted here, we only know that it couldn't be run, but that could be for another reason.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JasonConti, and yes, @fkraiem, I am sure that `/sbin/ldconfig` is missing, I checked.  At this point I think my problem is that I am missing some packages (such as libc-bin), so I will check back once I have investigated further.

Comment: Yup, it was my debootstrap line.  Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
I had not specified a complete list of packages (`libc-bin` and `dash` were missing, among many others), which prevented debootstrap from doing its job.  I ended up using an updated list of packages, which solved my problem.